# JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory, Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the location of your Java installation

Tags: java, android-studio, environment-variables, java-home

F:\Project_Path>gradlew appDistributionLogin

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files\Java\openjdk

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
when running the firebase app distribution command on the android studio terminal. I have already set the JDK location in my system & the environment variable still getting this error.

[image]

Comment: Does `C:\Program Files\Java\openjdk` contain `bin` folder?

Comment: seems pretty self explaining, no?

Comment: How did you install JDK on your computer?

Comment: Does the variable "Path" contain the value `%JAVA_HOME%\bin;`?

Answer (score 5):

Make sure the path 'C:\Program Files\Java\openjdk' is valid(ensure correct spellings) and existed in your system.

Ideally value for JAVA_HOME should be pointed to the Home directory of the java installed in your system.

[image: Example JAVA_HOME directory]

Comment: This, without /bin